# Unable to submit default value set in zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-form

Am new to zf2 using zend form, Hydrator.
I have managed to set the field element like

```
$this->add(array(
  'type' => 'text',
  'name' => 'name',
  'options' => array(
    'label' => 'Facility Name'
  )
));

$this->add(array(
  'type' => 'text',
  'name' => 'createdOn',
  'attributes' => array(
    'value' => date('d-m-Y'),         
  )
));
```

Displayed only Facility Name and not created On in the phtml

```
echo $this->formElementerrors($form->get('name'));
echo $this->formLabel($form->get('name'));
echo $this->formInput($form->get('name'));
```

When I submit the form, It keeps on giving me the error
Column 'createdOn' cannot be null

How can I set the default as current date to created on field and Submit with the form submit.

Answer (score 0):

Value is filtered [from the attributes array here](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/blob/master/src/Element.php#L192).
But to set default values in a form element [there is a `setValue` method](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/blob/master/src/Element.php#L304):

You can set it on element...

```
$element->setValue( 'some value' );
```

or you can use the form `populateValues` method.

Comment: But if i set attributes value for the text field, It works perfectly. This problem occur with the hidden field for me.